# How to handle multiple API calls on a cron job Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have been doing some research lately to find which is the best way to perform multiple API calls using a cron job in Laravel no success.

So my issue is I have to send a loan application to multiple banks, my cron:

Controller:

```
.
.
foreach($banks as $bank){

 $job = $this->dispatch(SendToBank($transaction));

} 
.
.
```

Then cron Job:

```
public function handle(){

  $response = app($this->bank)::sendApplication($this->transaction);

}
```

**Question:**

How to add delay to a job since an api response may take 10 sec to get completed.

I know I can do `$job->delay(time)` but in my case it does not work as expected since `foreach` fires the jobs in speed of light.

When an api call fails I want to fail that job and place it back to queue after 15 mins ?

Note that if api call fails `$response` will be empty, what I have tried is to throw an exception if response is empty. But is it considered as a failed job when an exception is thrown ?

Can someone which is the best approach on making multiple api calls on a cron job ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple calls in parallel with guzzle:
http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/client.html#sending-requests-in-parallel

```
use Guzzle\Common\Exception\MultiTransferException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

try {
    $responses = $client->send(array(
        $client->get('http://www.google.com/'),
        $client->head('http://www.google.com/'),
        $client->get('https://www.github.com/')
    ));
} catch (MultiTransferException $e) {

    echo "The following exceptions were encountered:\n";
    foreach ($e as $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage() . "\n";
    }

    echo "The following requests failed:\n";
    foreach ($e->getFailedRequests() as $request) {
        echo $request . "\n\n";
    }

    echo "The following requests succeeded:\n";
    foreach ($e->getSuccessfulRequests() as $request) {
        echo $request . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Another option is to use promises, although a javascript (node) application is better suited to this, there are options to this with php:
https://github.com/amphp/amp

I would recommend to take a look at queuing to handle your calls. It is more often than not the best solution to these types of technical challenges.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

In that case you can define different ways of handling failure/success;
a failed api call should then requeue the job.

Comment: The issue its not how to send multiple calls with guzzle, its how to process multiple calls on a cron job!

Comment: My suggestion was to use Guzzle in your cron job to do your calls synchronously.
See the updated answer above for an example